# How can I create full screen slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Can someone help me to create full screen slides exactly like following website...
Browser scrollbar is hidden, when scroll up/down or press up/down key slides moves to next screen and active dot changed as per slide.

http://vaalentin.github.io/2015/

```js
$("nav a").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 body {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .box {
  display: table;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
 }
 .box { background-color: rgb(179, 235, 255); }
 .box + .box { background-color: rgb(217, 255, 228); }
 .box + .box + .box { background-color: rgb(255, 221, 255); }
 .box + .box + .box + .box { background-color: rgb(255, 190, 190); }
 .box + .box + .box + .box + .box { background-color: rgb(253, 176, 255); }
 .box + .box + .box + .box + .box + .box { background-color: rgb(0, 26, 73); color: #fff; }
 .box + .box + .box + .box + .box + .box + .box { background-color: rgb(23, 0, 4); }

 .inner {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1vw;
 }
 nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
 }
  nav a:link,
  nav a:visited {
   display: block;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: #222;
   border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
 <a href="#home"></a>
 <a href="#services"></a>
 <a href="#team"></a>
 <a href="#work"></a>
 <a href="#process"></a>
 <a href="#faq"></a>
 <a href="#contact"></a>
</nav>

<div id="home" class="box">
 <div class="inner">
  <h1>Home</h1>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="services" class="box">
 <div class="inner">
  <h1>Services</h1>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="team" class="box">
 <div class="inner">
  <h1>Team</h1>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="work" class="box">
 <div class="inner">
  <h1>Recent Work</h1>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="process" class="box">
 <div class="inner">
  <h1>Process</h1>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="faq" class="box">
 <div class="inner">
  <h1>FAQ</h1>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="contact" class="box">
 <div class="inner">
  <h1>Contact</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement something? If so please post your code and be specific about question.

Comment: @prudhvi I added snippet.

Comment: You know about the `:nth-cild()` selector, right? From what I can see, this seems to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at impress.js it gives you an already working framework, you just have to compose the elements.

https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/

**EDIT**

Other framework is fullPage.js

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

Comment: Thanks for your input but I couldn't achieve my target with it, what I actually need is scroll up/down and arrow key up down functionality that moves my slide next/previous.

Comment: I think that the new one is what you are looking for.